# Can we block, restrict, control cookies set on browser by from external sources?

Tags: nginx, cookies, local-storage, httpcookie

Can we restrict/block cookies from being set on browser from external sources? For example in the below picture of usatoday (just used for reference) we can see that various cookies are being set by varirous partners besides its own cookies set by ([www.usatoday.com](http://www.usatoday.com))

However as a website owner I might be uncomfortable with cookies that are being set by parties like -

```
us.u-openx.net
acdn.adnxs.com
ads.pubmatic.com
eus.rubiconproject.com
ssum.casalemedia.com
```

The above cookies are no way related to the website functionality and they are mostly advertising cookies which are also able to collect data about my user through their own ways.

I want to find an option where I might allow ads.pubmatic.com and eus.rubiconproject.com only to set cookies whereas rest of the partners should not be able to set any cookies on my website.

Is there anyway I can set a server side solution that will monitor and control this?
perhaps something like "Set-Cookie" header in my Nginx web server or any other approach.

This would be of much help if you can let me know the same.

Regards
A

[image]